# Code::Blocks pthread example can not compile

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, pthreads, codeblocks

Maybe this questions is easy but I can't figure it out how to resolve it:
I try to compile an example which has `pthreas` on **windows 7** (64bit), with **Code Blocks** I downloaded the prebuild library and set up **building_options**: the path for the compiler `pthreadLib\include` and the linker to `pthreadLib\lib\x64`
The program is:

```
extern "C"
 {
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
 }
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std ;

void  * function1(void * argument);
void  * function2(void * argument);

int main( void )
{
    pthread_t t1, t2 ; // declare 2 threads.

    pthread_create( &t1, NULL, function1,NULL); // create a thread running function1
    pthread_create( &t2, NULL, function2,NULL); // create a thread running function2

    Sleep(1);

    return 0;
}

void * function1(void * argument)
{
    cout << " hello " << endl ;
    Sleep(2); // fall alseep here for 2 seconds...
    return 0;
}

void * function2(void * argument)
{
    cout << " world "  << endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

In case I comment `pthread_create();` function, than it builds. So `pthread_t` is recognized as a type. 
When I try to compile with `pthread_create` I get an error:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -L..\libs\Pre-built.2\lib\x64 -LD:\DropBox\WorkUT\Programs\MyODP\libs -o bin\Release\RIP.exe obj\Release\main.o  -s  ..\libs\Pre-built.2\lib\x64\libpthreadGC2.a ..\libs\Pre-built.2\lib\x64\pthreadVC2.lib
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x36): undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_create'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Do I have to make additional setups in `C::B`? I tired to add the linker command `-lpthread` but is not recognized.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482658/libpthread-in-mingw-does-not-find-the-libraries.

Comment: I saw that post. In the error massage fist raw: `mingw32-g++.exe -o bin\Release\RIP.exe obj\Release\main.o  -s libpthreadGC2.a pthreadVC2.lib` 2 libs are linked automatically when I gave the path. Mentioned that `-lpthread` is not recognized when I include manually in `C::B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 2 days I figured it out.

First: I installed the [minGW 64](http://www.drangon.org/mirror.fcgi?num=3&fname=mingw-w64-bin-x86_64-20131018.7z) for Windows OS. 
Next: I set up `C::B` to use the `minGW_64` after this [post](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=14180.0;prev_next=prev).
Moreover: I added to the linker libs `..\libs\Pre-built.2\lib\x64\libpthreadGC2.a` and `..\libs\Pre-built.2\lib\x64\pthreadVC2.lib`. Finally, I added to my project the `pthreadGC2.dll` (64bit version!).

Lesson learned, don't mix lib. and compiler with 86 and 64.

Answer (score -1):

For Linux
Use sleep(1) in stead of Sleep(1)

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: The error says `undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_create'`, it has nothing to do with `sleep`...